# Add build step in asp.net form website

Tags: asp.net, webforms

My website has JavaScript files but I want to generate minified version. In this way I only have to commit development version to version control system.

I have experience on Gradle and Grunt, it seems what I need is to add a build step in asp.net, which is to invoke a JavaScript minifier.

I find `<buildProviders>` promissing, where `JavaScriptMinifier.JavaScriptMinificationProvider, JavaScriptMinifier` is my own minifier.

```xml
<buildProviders>
  <remove extension=".js" />
  <add extension=".js" type="JavaScriptMinifier.JavaScriptMinificationProvider, JavaScriptMinifier" />
</buildProviders>
```

The provider seems to only minify js file in App_Code folder. How do I make it work for js files in other folders? Am I using the right tool?

Note my website uses dynamic compilation.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but have you seen the [Bundler & Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier) extension for Visual Studio?  It might get you to the same end goal.